# What is the best strategy for Samurai vs Zombie Defense to protect my Sacred Gate?

Tags: samurai-vs-zombies

I always seem to get dominated by zombies as I am either not strong enough yet, or I have made poor choices spending my leadership points [on troops that are not good to fight against specific zombies].

I normally spend the majority of my points on the sword warriors.  If I can get a good line of those to stay alive, I purchase bowmen, and save for a priest.

Also, I tend to run behind enemy lines to take out their archers.  I manly use the Lethargy and divine ability.

I am currently on wave 16, and I am getting trampled!  How can I survive this wave and waves to follow ??  Are there specific troops I should upgrade / purchase?

**I am looking for methods that do NOT involve spending money IRL.**

Comment: Maybe some plants could help...

Comment: What is troop trample? It seems to show up every now and then in svz 2 discussions but I can't seem to find it in my app (I am stuck at level 29).

Answer (score 3):

I have made it to level 50 for the 11th time without spending real money.  I think in the early game, you should just upgrade the farmers and then your life total.  You don't need better sword or arrows, or gate health, etc.  Farmers are best, as the can be fully upgraded with coins, not gems.  I saved all my gems up to get troop trample upgraded then leadership.  I use troop trample and lethargy exclusively, and my line up is farmers, bowman, swordsmith, frostie the bowman, and one free spot.  I never need the fourth.

Now I have over 1 million coins and cannot spend them.  They are completely useless.  Everything is upgraded fully, coin-wise.  I save the charms until level 40-50, when it gets tough.  I will often try a few times first to decide which charm to use - they are precious, and now, if I run out, I will not be able to progress.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Im stuck on 33. I didnt put any points on my allies until I made it here, But now im stuck and have gotten a bit desperate. At the beginning the points I did use were strickly for his sword, bow, archers for the gate and the gates health itself. I put points on lethargy and now on divine. which I had none previously, until 33. Theres a lot of strike and back away that I did. But the main strategy I used which worked was make a defense guy, just one, because there was no point in multiple being that they kill multiple targets at once, and backing his up with as many archers as i could. Then when whoever my defense guy was before he would die id send another out. Also I would try and slow down the monsters as much as possible with just my guy as too upgrade as fast as possible to max. Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 1):

I won level 50 with

1. 2 revive - great with the new discount pack 5x for 20 gems.
2. hero - max till the use of gems
3. gate max (no gems required)
4. archers max (no gems)
5. farmers max  (no gems)

Run all the way to demon gate. Kill off as much minor minions to start. Slow boss down. Wait till leadership is max. Only use farmers to block.

Use 1 sushi, samurai would die about 51-60% gate damage
Use 1st revive - kill 2 spider lady.

Keep framer defence coming. Samurai would die around 75-80% gate damage. Now use 2nd revive - (kill big red demon). I use the abilities slash (max without gems) and trample. No charms used.

Level 50 is much easier than level 33. Farm for coins on level 29/39/49. Do not win. Just get coins and win only with 2 or more gold boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I had Hero at level 8, farmers at level 10, lethargy at level 5, troop trample at level 1, sword and bow to level 5, warding bell to level 2, and gate to level 3.  That's it - no revive, sushi, etc.

Took me a while to actually implement the strategy: Basically, attack with hero right out of the gate - and kill as many minions as possible.  Quick hits here and there on the boss. Attack and back up. Lethargy and troop trample, then level up to 4th level before getting the farmers if possible.  At that point you will be in the 60 to 100 level.  Farmers are never ending at that point. Stand behind them, farmers, shoot arrows, lethargy, troop trample. Eventually, noone is standing except for the big boss.  Be very careful when you attack him though.

Answer (score 1):

My strategy is to summon Assassins as many as possible (MASSIVELY-keep your left thumb summoning Assassins until the stage is over), they're pretty good because:

1. Cheap, these little assassins costs 5 resources - cheapest unit you will find along with Farmer
2. They can do short and long range attacks, basically they can attack ground and air units such as flying squirrels and Tengu guys (red masks with long noses)
3. Fast, as soon as they finish the enemy they will head on to the next target - this will buy you some time to:

   1. Recover
   2. Pick up the some coins
   3. Gain some space that will eventually push down a bit those freaking zombies

I finished the game twice without Revives and keep using those Charms to earn more coins, gifts, pots, sushi's, charms, pachinko balls. And keep a couple of Peace Charms for the last level -50, you will need it if you don't want to purchase GLU Credits in order to level up your samurai abilities. Good luck, and have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade farmer and assasin to max. Use gold coins to raise leadership. Combined with group trample and lethargy, you're unstoppable.

Answer (score 1):

My strategy is a little bit different. I'm a fan of slow but sure strategy. I use lethargy and troop trample. On my troops, i used panzer samurai and frosty the bowman. I strictly use my diamonds to upgrade sword lvl up to lvl 10. bow lvl 5. Frosty lvl 4 and panzer lvl 5. Hero lvl 9, sacred gate lvl 3. Lethargy lvl 5 and troops trample lvl 1.

Panzer, once you get into lvl 5, is a hard wall to breach in lvl before 50, but is still a weakling to the lvl 50 boss. Especially when the spider zombie comes around. So my strategy is:

Early stage: use your hero to fend off the enemy's army. Meanwhile, upgrade your leadership to the max without even summon any unit. Use lethargy and troop trample to defend your position and kill as many small armies as you can, and keep the boss busy pounding on you while you evade it, so it won't step much further. Don't worry, before you realized it, you'll be already kill a large portion of the earlier troops because the game spawns a weakling troops in the early on stage 50th.

Middle stage: by the time you max out the leadership and able to summon your first panzer samurai, the boss will most likely already passed the middle bridge. Usually he will be around the warding bell position. Now is the time to be smart and fend off enemies attack from behind the panzer samurai's line. Usually a panzer unit will die in about 5-7 seconds. That's why you really need all the slow in the world. Keep summoning the panzer, but alternate between the panzer and the frostie summoning in the way: 3 panzer, 1 frostie. You need to ALWAYS stay at the front line, just in case the panzer supply is short. If the small fast round enemies get past you, let them be. Just kill them using the troops ability. Or if your gate is not that strong enough, strike lethargy when those small enemies come, and kill them fast. Do this until all the enemies that accompany the boss are wiped out, leaving the boss alone. Don't worry, it may seems hard at first, but once your frostie population is enough, you will see a never ending lethargy. :) oh yeah, whenever you see those enemy's bowmans behind the boss, hit lethargy, and quickly wipe them out. They can be a serious threat to your panzer if accumulated.

Late stage: when the smaller enemies had been wiped out, this is where the easy parts comes in. Just keep summoning the panzer, as the boss will never be able to wipe your panzer with his very-slow attack, thanks to the frosties. But your real damage will be coming from the troops trample attack. So just keep bashing the lethargy-troops ability, and panzer summoning, until he's dead.

I didn't use any sushis, tea pots, or charms with this strategy. :) but yeah, i failed a lot before "getting it right", because this strategy also needs mastering of the hit-and-run hero strategy. The good thing about this strategy is that you don't need to be distracted by keep mashing on the farmer / assassin button. Therefore, you can concentrate on maneuvering your hero, and keep engaged.

Answer (score -1):

I would say that the best way is to farm coins at the designated levels, or any that gives a good amount of coins whether you lose or quit. Just quit right before winning (at 90% if you want to be safe).

Maximize farmers as soon as possible because it helps quite a bit as you can spam them once you reach level 3 leadership in battles.

Keep in mind that air after level 20 gets tough: you might want to get bows to level 4 or 5 so you can compensate against those air attack squads. It should be fairly easy with the build that Wawa says but I would at Lethargy 5 and Trample and maybe combo with Frostie if you have him.

I've given the assassins a try, but they don't seem to be worthwhile with maxed farmers and swordsmith. Bowmen are still more usable than assassin at this point + if you spawn rifleman they're great.

One thing to note is that to get the special Villagers, the ones from boxes, I've only gottem them via using revive: I think this is by design. I always beat games with 1-2 boxes and have never gotten them until lvl 47-48, which is when I started to use revives.